# Линейная регрессия

Tags: математика, численные-методы, регрессия

У меня вопрос относительно пункта 3.26.Существует ли в рассматриваемой задаче минимум?
Если да, то единственен ли он?
Из соображений того, что в линейную регрессию входят уравнения вида y=ax+b,а это уравнение прямой .У прямой нет минимума, но не зная точного док-ва своего вопроса, боюсь сразу отвечать. Думаю лучше прислушаться ко мнению более опытных программистов-математиков.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот эта штука не то ?
                        https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Это то,на 1 вопрос хоть что-то есть.На 2 нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну понятно что минимум есть! Это - сумма квадратов, т.е. положительных величин. Меньше 0 она быть не может. А больше - сколько угодно. Берем `b` близким к бесконечности :) и получаем значение больше любого наперед заданного.

А значит, какой-то минимум - существует.

Ну, а (3.27) получается из (3.26) диффиренцированием по `a` и `b` и приравниванием производных к нулю - для вычисления экстремума.

Comment: Спасибо @Harry ,а раз линейная регрессия является частным случаем решения переопределённой системы линейных алгебраических уравнений ,значит есть вероятность, что этот минимум не единственен?

Comment: Гм... о единственности я как-то не задумывался... в принципе да, может быть и не единственным - например, если точка единственная, то минимум дает любая прямая, проходящая через эту точку :) Но если хотите всерьез разобраться - то советую вот эту [книжицу](https://www.twirpx.com/file/103074/) - на год выпуска не смотрите, книга очень неплохая... Есть еще одно издание, 1962 года - вобщем, что найдете.

Comment: еще не было ни одного вопроса,где бы вы доступно не ответили на мой вопрос :) @Harry

Comment: Да, система-то ничуть не переопределенная! Два уравнения, две неизвестные - a и b. Решение единственное :)

Comment: Если система уравнений 3.27 однозначно разрешима, то минимум единственен. Осталось вспомнить условия когда это так.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Скорее так - мы получаем экстремум. А вот минимум это, максимум или седловая точка - это можно исследовать :) Но поскольку сумма квадратов относительно a и b является квадратичной формой, то отсюда - из ее конкретных свойств получается, что это минимум, и минимум единственный.